# Is there a way to list all the files within a directory in a different language?(not English)

Tags: python, operating-system, python-2.x

I'm writing a code that lists all the the files within a specific directory.
I'm using the os module and the command:

os.listdir(path)

However, if a file is in my native language, Hebrew, it prints gibberish.

������ 1.docx

If I print the whole list the item shows in the list as:

\xe0\xf1\xee\xe1\xec\xf8 1.docx

Is there a way to make it print in my language and not gibberish?

Comment: How are you using running this script?

Comment: I run it with Pycharm console.

Comment: What happens if you run it outside of Pycharm?

Comment: Running with cmd gets me similar results:     α±εß∞° 1.docx

Comment: I  was able to do `os.listdir(path)` and was able to print ` .txtנצר מטעי מעשה יד.txt ` which I assume is hebrew!

Comment: It is Hebrew, but for me it prints gibberish.

Comment: python2 or python3?, I used python3.7 and works for me, something else might be going on, try taking the file name and running `print(filename)`

Comment: Also, what is the OS?

Comment: python2. My project, where I use this code, only supports python2.

Comment: os is windows 10.

Comment: I have no knowledge on any particular changes I've made.

Comment: Can reproduce on win10 if i use cmd. Spyder behaves just fine, and displays the characters correctly. Cmd however, throws a bunch of question marks. What's funny is that if i take the string of question marks and paste it elsewhere, it shows up just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console)

Comment: @Ofir I've retracted my dupe vote, but the linked Q&A may be useful for getting output in the cmd window.